# How to bulk add date before file extension on Linux

Tags: linux, date, xargs

Lets say I have 
a.txt, b.txt and I want to add the date to see:
a_MMDDYYY.txt, b_MMDDYYYY.txt

I'm trying to use `xargs` and `basename` in the following way:

```
basename -s .txt -a *.txt | xargs -n1 -i cp {}.txt {}_$date.txt
```

I know that the end of my command is not correct, I'm just trying to figure out how to use it and how to inject the builtin "date" into xargs.

Thanks

Comment: may be better for UNIX SE ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command substitution like this:

```
basename -s .txt -a *.txt | xargs -n1 -i cp {}.txt {}_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt
```

See this link for date formatting examples: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/

You can learn more about command substitution here: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
printf '%s\0' *.txt | parallel -0 cp {} {.}_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt
```

Or if there are only few files:

```
parallel -0 cp {} {.}_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt ::: *.txt
```

(Also: https://xkcd.com/1179/)